# Material-UI table overflows its table wrapper

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

my material-ui table resizes and scrolls horizontally just fine, however, the table element and its children spill over, invisible off the right side of the page.
Here is a gif of the behavior. https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXuHj.jpg

And an image of the inspected elements.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNgtl.jpg

What might be causing this behavior?

```
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3
  },
  table: {},
  tableWrapper: {
    overflowX: 'auto'
  }
});
```

.

```
<Paper className={classes.root}>
        <EnhancedTableToolbar
          numSelected={selected.length}
          tableTitle={'Accounts'}
        >
          <AccountFilterList />
        </EnhancedTableToolbar>
        <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
          <Table className={classes.table} aria-labelledby='tableTitle'>
            <EnhancedTableHead
              numSelected={selected.length}
              order={order}
              orderBy={orderBy}
              onSelectAllClick={this.handleSelectAllClick}
              onRequestSort={this.handleRequestSort}
              rowCount={data.length}
              columnData={columnData}
            />
            <TableBody>
              {data
                .slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                .map(n => {
                  const isSelected = this.isSelected(n.ref);
                  return (
                    <TableRow
                      hover
                      onClick={event => this.handleRowClick(event, n.ref)}
                      role='checkbox'
                      aria-checked={isSelected}
                      tabIndex={-1}
                      key={n.ref}
                      selected={isSelected}
                    >
                      <TableCell padding='checkbox'>
                        <Checkbox
                          checked={isSelected}
                          onChange={event => this.handleClick(event, n.ref)}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>
                        <Avatar
                          alt={n.name}
                          src={`//logo.clearbit.com/${n.clearBit}`}
                          onError={e => {
                            e.target.src =
                              'https://doxhze3l6s7v9.cloudfront.net/app/static/img/company-default-img.png';
                          }}
                        />
                      </TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{n.name}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell>{n.owner}</TableCell>
                      <TableCell numeric>{n.dateCreated}</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                  );
                })}
              {emptyRows > 0 && (
                <TableRow style={{ height: 49 * emptyRows }}>
                  <TableCell colSpan={6} />
                </TableRow>
              )}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </div>
        <TablePagination
          component='div'
          count={data.length}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          page={page}
          backIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Previous Page'
          }}
          nextIconButtonProps={{
            'aria-label': 'Next Page'
          }}
          onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        />
      </Paper>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Parent wrapper must be having some width specified, thats why its taking that space in the right. Check whether that empty space is caused by the table elements or the parent wrapper element (AppBar).

Comment: The image I included of the 'table' element is the top-most element to show any overflow. There are no elements that wrap it whose width goes off the screen.

Comment: just to be sure, if you remove the table element is it still having that empty space. I had a similar experience like this and my app bar component was causing the issue for me.

Comment: Just checked. Removing the table removes the overflow. Thanks though.

Comment: It seems that a material-ui style is taking precedent  over the styles that I input. Even setting the max-width on the table does nothing.
https://imgur.com/a/PmUcIJs

Comment: if that's the case try to use the inline style attribute to override it and please check the tableWrapper overflow auto and see whether its causing the problem.

Comment: Inline styles are also ignored. But only when they are less than the width supplied by the material-ui style. The tableWrapper appears to be working fine and has an appropriate width. https://imgur.com/a/FTEleP4